# PHP resize image, kinda works

Tags: php, resize

This code has been giving me issues for a few weeks now and haven't come close to solving it...

```
function create_thumbnail($source, $destination, $thumb_width){
    $extension = get_image_extension($source);
    $size = getimagesize($source);
    $imageWidth  = $newWidth  = $size[0];
    $imageHeight = $newheight = $size[1];

    if ($imageWidth > $thumb_width || $imageHeight > $thumb_width)
    {
        // Calculate the ratio
        $xscale = ($imageWidth/$thumb_width);
        $yscale = ($imageHeight/$thumb_width);
        $newWidth  = ($yscale > $xscale) ? round($imageWidth * (1/$yscale)) : round($imageWidth * (1/$xscale));
        $newHeight = ($yscale > $xscale) ? round($imageHeight * (1/$yscale)) : round($imageHeight * (1/$xscale));
    }

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

    switch ($extension)
    {
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            $imageCreateFrom = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
            $store = 'imagejpeg';
            break;

        case 'png':
            $imageCreateFrom = 'imagecreatefrompng';
            $store = 'imagepng';
            break;

        case 'gif':
            $imageCreateFrom = 'imagecreatefromgif';
            $store = 'imagegif';
            break;

        default:
            return false;
    }

    $container = $imageCreateFrom($source);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $container, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
    return $store($newImage, $destination);
}
```

Now it works fine, but the space that these resized images are going into are 200(height) by 225(width) and sometimes I will get an images that are tall and skinny and some images that are short and wide and that makes it difficult to fit them in the space, ideally if I can resizes these images with them being squished or cut off, but I'm not sure if that's possible... Is it?

If that is not possible I guess I am looking to adjust this code so if its an image that is tall and skinny to resize with a height of 200 and if an image is wide and short to resize to width 225...I hope this makes sense.

Anyhow any tips, advice or anything would be appreciated.

I tried to run mschr code (which is below in answers) and got these errors

```
Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 321

Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 323

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/include/header.php:7) in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 325

Warning: imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 329

Warning: imagedestroy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 334
```

Comment: your function returns true/false and sets $destination, the paste i gave sends images to outputstream (writes them).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i do it; $w and $h are requested dimension, $nHeight and $nWidth resulting dim - upholding aspect ratio

```
function thumb($img, $w = 100, $h = 100, $fill = true) {
    if (!extension_loaded('gd') && !extension_loaded('gd2')) {
        trigger_error("No dispones de la libreria GD para generar la imagen.", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    $imgInfo = getimagesize($img);
    switch ($imgInfo[2]) {
        case 1: $im = imagecreatefromgif($img); break;
        case 2: $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);  break;
        case 3: $im = imagecreatefrompng($img); break;
        default:  trigger_error('Tipo de imagen no reconocido.', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
    }
    // note, how the lesser ratio is chosen
    if ($imgInfo[0] <= $w && $imgInfo[1] <= $h && !$fill) {
        $nHeight = $imgInfo[1];
        $nWidth = $imgInfo[0];
    }else{
        if ($w/$imgInfo[0] < $h/$imgInfo[1]) {
            $nWidth = $w;
            $nHeight = $imgInfo[1]*($w/$imgInfo[0]);
        }else{
            $nWidth = $imgInfo[0]*($h/$imgInfo[1]);
            $nHeight = $h;
        }
    }

    $nWidth = round($nWidth);
    $nHeight = round($nHeight);

    $newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);

    imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $imgInfo[0], $imgInfo[1]);

    header("Content-type: ". $imgInfo['mime']);

    switch ($imgInfo[2]) {
        case 1: imagegif($newImg); break;
        case 2: imagejpeg($newImg);  break;
        case 3: imagepng($newImg); break;
        default:  trigger_error('Imposible mostrar la imagen.', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
    }

    imagedestroy($newImg);
}
```

Comment: what would I replace this with in my function?

Comment: filling in rest, just use the full function =)

Comment: im just confused with the variables in here so when I run this script `imagecopyresampled($newImage, $container, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);` do it replace is like this `imagecopyresampled($newImage, $container, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);`

Comment: `Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 321`

Comment: `Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 323`

Comment: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/include/header.php:7) in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 325`

Comment: `Warning: imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 329

Warning: imagedestroy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 334`

Answer (score 0):

Ah i see.. You wish to set the $destination with your imagedata, the above post shows a function which will serve the image through a GET request like so:

http://localhost/thumbnail.php?w=500&h=300&file=./images/bigimage.png

while thumbnail.php contains the function 'thumb' and calls it with

```
<? thumb($_GET['file'], $_GET['w'], $_GET['h']); ?>
```

What you want is to 
1) Modify the parameters thumb takes into accepting $destination
2) remove the header("Content-type...") line
3) rewrite in the last switch-case to:

```
switch ($imgInfo[2]) {
    case 1: return imagegif($newImg, $destination);
    case 2: return imagejpeg($newImg, $destination);
    case 3: return imagepng($newImg, $destination);
    default:  trigger_error('Imposible mostrar la imagen.', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
}
 return false;
```